# Nodes deleting after being printed

Tags: c

So I'm trying to write a program that does a couple different operates on a set of nodes I've built. However, it seems whenever I generate the nodes, then print them, they get lost or deleted. My code is as follows:

```
void insertNodeAtTail(DlistRef dl, Info g){
/* insert a new node at the end of the list with value g */
    NodeRef n = initializeNode(g);
    if (dl->head == NULL){
        //Empty list case
        dl->tail = n;
        dl->head = n;
    } else {
        //Not empty list case
        n->prev = dl->tail;
        dl->tail->next = n;
        dl->tail = n;
    }
}/*insertNodeAtTail*/

void insertNodeAtHead(DlistRef dl, Info g){
/* insert a new node with value g at the beginning of the list */
NodeRef n = initializeNode(g);
if (dl->head == NULL){
    //Empty list case
    dl->head = n;
    dl->tail = n;
}else{
    //Not empty list case
    n->next = dl->head;
    dl->head->prev = n;
    dl->head = n;
}/*if+else*/
}/*insertNodeAtHead*/

void printListForward(DlistRef dl, char* title){
/* print list items in forward order starting at head */
/* title can be used to add a descriptive title for the list output */
    if (dl->head == NULL){
        printf("Empty list\n");
    } /*if*/

    while (dl->head != NULL){
        printf("%d ", dl->head->item->info);
        dl->head = dl->head->next;
    }/*while*/
}/*printListForward*

int main(){
char string[] = "myList";
DlistRef dl = initializeDlist();
int i;

for(i=0; i <= 15; i++){
    if(i%2 != 0){
        insertNodeAtTail(dl,i);
    }
}

printf("Forward: ");
printListForward(dl, string);

    insertNodeAtHead(dl, 0);
insertNodeAtTail(dl, 17);

printf("\n");

printf("Forward: ");
printListForward(dl, string);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I suspect it is in my insertNodeAtTail function, where I've forgot to link something. The output of my program here is:

Forward: 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15
Forward: 0 17

It should append 0 and 17 to the front and back respectively, making the 2nd set go to:
Forward: 0 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17.

Thanks :)

Comment: Is `DlistRef` a pointer?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wanted to keep it under the code limit. Any of the Refs are pointers.

Comment: I'm not positive (hence not posting as an answer), but instead of directly modifying head: dl->head = dl->head->next;   I would make a temporary pointer, set it equal to head (for iteration purposes) and modify that, instead. Maybe this is bad practice, but it's how I've always done it. Some feedback in either direction would be good, as well as whether it works or not for you.

Comment: In `main`, there is a call to `insertNodeAtTail(dl,i)`. The function `insertNodeAtTail` has arguments `DlistRef dl, Info g`.

Is 'Info' a typedef for `int`?

Comment: Ricky, I'll try that, seems logical. And Keith, yes it is :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is on the iteration of the list. On the printListForward function you must create a temporal variable for the iteration, because when you say dl->head = dl->head->next; the reference on memory of the list is overrite by the next. The last iteration result when you set the head to null. Then when you print the list you clean the list also.

Please change the print function for this function

```
void printListForward(DlistRef dl, char* title){
/* print list items in forward order starting at head */
/* title can be used to add a descriptive title for the list output */
    if (dl->head == NULL){
        printf("Empty list\n");
    } /*if*/

    NodeRef current = dl->head;
    while (dl->head != NULL){
        printf("%d ", current->item->info);
        current = current->next;
    }/*while*/
}/*printListForward*
```

Comment: Furthermore, shouldnt you do the "NodeRef current = dl->head;" right at the top, and then replace "dl-head" with "current" in the if statement?

Comment: The code you've currently pasted makes my program FC, however, if I replace "dl->head" in the while loop with "current", everything works as it should. Thanks :)